# Creating a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec

For 2 days I am trying to make a `cocoapod` in `swift` using `Xcode 7.1.1`

Problem is when I install pod using `pod install`, my pod files get integrated with the project but I can not use my pod files. The reference is missing. The project does not recognize my pod files.

Tutorials I have tried:

1. https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create
2. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332
3. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/creating-a-cocoapod.html

Both `pod lib lint` and `pod spec lint` passes validation. Also I was successful in `pod trunk push`

You can get the pod in your project using

```
pod 'WARDoorView', '~> 0.1.2'
```

You can try the pod using

```
pod try WARDoorView
```

If you download the repo, the example project has compiler error in `ViewController.swift`:

> Use of undeclared type 'WARDoorView'

But I can see the `WARDoorView.swift` under `pods`

The repository is at
 
https://github.com/rishi420/WARDoorView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

God... after 3 days I'm able to find the issue.

I had to make my class `public` and any function I want to call from outside `public`.

```
public class WARDoorView: UIView { ...

public func doorOpen(angle: Double ...

public func doorClose(duration: NSTimeInterval ...
```

I thought `public` was the default. I was wrong.

New pod using

```
pod 'WARDoorView', '~> 1.0.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded your project and open `'WARDoorView.xcworkspace'` file, however as you mentioned I didn't get any error it build and run properly. Close door is also working as expected. If you are using `'WARDoorView.xcodeproj'` file, you'll get error because after integration of pod we need to use workspace file.

Comment: I was trying many things for test. I've manually added the `WARDoorView` folder to test the linking problem. That folder is supposed to come from the pod file. Plz delete the folder and test again. Thanks for trying.

Comment: i've deleted the manual added folder myself and updated the git repository. you can download again to test